# How to force window to keep a specific ratio in GTK+?

Tags: python, gtk

I have a `GtkWindow` I'd like to be resizable, but constrained in its ratio proportions. What is the easiest way to achieve that? Should I manually resize it on each `configure-event`, or is there an easier way to do it?

My widget hierarchy looks like that:

```
GtkWindow
  GtkBox
    GtkToolbar
    GtkBox
      GtkAspectFrame
```

---

From the answers I got, I tried something like that:

```
    gh = Gdk.Geometry()
    gh.min_aspect = 0.5
    gh.max_axpect = 0.5
    w.set_geometry_hints(None, gh, Gdk.WindowHints.ASPECT)
```

However, I still can resize my window with any aspect I want. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Use gtk_window_set_geometry_hints().  You need to use the min_aspect and max_aspect fields in the GdkGeometry structure.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer suggests, you could use [gtk_window_set_geometry_hints()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-geometry-hints). The documentation says:

> **This function sets up hints about how a window can be resized by the user. You can set a minimum and maximum size**; allowed resize
>   increments (e.g. for xterm, you can only resize by the size of a
>   character); **aspect ratios**; and more.

The function's prototype is as follows:

```
void gtk_window_set_geometry_hints (GtkWindow *window,
                                    GtkWidget *geometry_widget,
                                    GdkGeometry *geometry,
                                    GdkWindowHints geom_mask);
```

You would specify the minimum and maximum width and height using the [GdkGeometry](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#GdkGeometry) data 
type which is a structure with the fields specified below:

```
struct GdkGeometry {
  gint min_width;
  gint min_height;
  gint max_width;
  gint max_height;
  gint base_width;
  gint base_height;
  gint width_inc;
  gint height_inc;
  gdouble min_aspect;
  gdouble max_aspect;
  GdkGravity win_gravity;
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried to use that function. However, the window still doesn't keep a fixed aspect ratio.

Comment: Perhaps you should also take into account the geom_mask argument as is described as: "mask indicating which struct fields should be paid attention to". Here's its definition: http://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#GdkWindowHints

Comment: If you look at the edited question, this is what I did (I think...)

Comment: You only provided that the hint is about ASPECT, but not WHEN to do this. You must provide also: Gdk.WindowHints.POS, Gdk.WindowHints.USER_POS, 
Gdk.WindowHints.USER_SIZE  etc. Better use `hints = Gdk.WindowHints(255)` Warning: These are hints. Aspect may vary depending on screen and minimums. A minimum width may allow "unmatched" height and vise versa.

Comment: This sort of works, but the window is extremely glitchy while resizing. Is there any way to fix that? I tried using `Gdk.WindowHints(255)`, but when I ran the code the window was just a microscopic strip that couldn't be resized, or even clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `max_axpect` to `max_aspect`.

That should help.